# asp.net core сформировать строку подключения к бд

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

Пытаюсь подключиться к базе MySql

Делаю так:

```
"DefaultConnection": "server=localhost;port=3306;database=mysite;user=root;password=admin",
```

и все работает,

но когда пытаюсь сгенерировать контроллер по модели, то автоматом формируется и новый контекст и строка подключения для него)

```
"myContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=myContext-3a5a2d6d-617a-42aa-9c0d-6cd3c4120c08;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

но при запуске приложения вылетает ошибка (как я понял связанная с логином). Как можно его явно указать? Или что-то другое поменять?

Comment: `Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;` - вы не того провайдера выбрали, это локальная база. `mssql != MySql` :)

Comment: @NewView я это понимаю, но не нашел инфу как сделать с mysql. Можно какйо-нибудь материал почитать по теме? `Server=(localdb)\\mysqllocaldb` - а так не будет работать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
        connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=mycontext;uid=root;password=********"/>
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
            type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"/>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"
            type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

`DbContext` конструктор, принимает либо имя строки подключения из `web.config` / `app.config`, либо можно определить любую строку для подключения прямо в конструкторе:

```
public DbContext(
    string MyConnectionString
)
```

Возможная более полная строка для `web.config` / `app.config` с дополнительными параметрами:

```
<add 
  name="MyConnection" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
  connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=mybase;
  uid=XXXXX;pwd=XXXXX" 
/>
```

обратите внимание на декларацию `pwd`, в чистой версии от MySql работает кажется этот вариант. Подробнее https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Если речь идёт о ASP.Core, то строка подключения должна формироваться примерно так:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DataAccessMySqlProvider": "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=leakhand; convert zero datetime=True"
  }
}
```

Хороший пример есть [тут](https://github.com/leakhand/LabDotNetCore/blob/master/appsettings.json)
и описание на [мсдн](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings#aspnet-core)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Эту инфу я читал уже в инете. Существует 3 проблемы из-за которых я могу ошибаться. 1) я использую asp.net core 2) Класс`DbContext` не принимает строку в качестве параметра (хотя судя по документации должен). 3) Файл appsetting.json - json формат (возможно я что-то не так пишу.

Comment: Тогда посмотрите исправленный вариант :)

Comment: заковыка была вообще не в этом...однако ваш ответ сподвигнул на действительное решение проблемы. Спасибо. +1 :)

Comment: Решение проблемы: скачал  [пакет](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql)  и добавил в сервисы инициализацию контекста для mysql `services.AddDbContext<myContext>(options =>
                    options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DataAccessMySqlProvider")));` было `UseSqlServer`.

Comment: Да, там в примере на гитхабе это есть, если бы вы превели в вопросе ещё и код инициализации, было бы проще найти причину, рад что помогло.